# Hidden flag default values

Tags: go

Go provides easy CLI switches aka flags.

```
var debug = flag.Bool("debug", false, "enable debugging")
var hostname = flag.String("hostname", "127.0.0.1", "hostname")
flag.Parse()
```

As expected this yields

```
> ./program -h
Usage:
    -debug
          enable debugging
    -hostname string
          hostname (default "127.0.0.1")
```

I would like to hide the `(default "127.0.0.1")` part of specific flags.

Searching on SO and around suggested use of flag.FlagSet.

```
var shown flag.FlagSet
var hidden flag.FlagSet
var debug = shown.Bool("debug", false, "enable debugging")
var hostname = hidden.String("hostname", "127.0.0.1", "hostname")
flag.Usage = func() {
    shown.PrintDefaults()
}
flag.Parse()
//shown.Parse(os.Args[0:]) // tried to solve "flag provided but not defined"
```

Output part shows only "debug" flag, however this breaks actual flag usage.

```
> ./program -debug
flag provided but not defined: -debug
Usage of ./program:
    -debug
          enable debugging
```

And this is not ideal either, since I would like to see the available flag, just hide the default value.

Desired output:

```
> ./program -h
Usage:
    -debug
          enable debugging
    -hostname string
          hostname
```

Comment: There is a reason why the defaults are printed. Don't disable them.

Comment: Have you tried give it an empty default value and check in your program it’s empty and substitute with real default?

Comment: @Volker please elaborate.

Comment: The information is useful for the user so don't hide it.

Comment: Please do not presume. Information is not useful for the user, because user needs only click-and-run. Excess information only confuses the user. Maybe the best course of action is to maintain 2 versions of the tool for users without flags and for powerusers with flags.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution so far is the one [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5165332/eugene-lisitsky) proposed. Thanks!

```
var debug = flag.Bool("debug", false, "enable debugging")
var hostname = flag.String("hostname", "", "hostname")
flag.Parse()

defaultHostname := "127.0.0.1"

if *hostname == "" {
    *hostname = defaultHostname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy & paste the codes from the source and remove the print default part.

```
flag.Usage = func() {
    f := flag.CommandLine
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(f.Output(), "Usage of %s:\n", os.Args[0])
    flag.VisitAll(func(flag_ *flag.Flag) {
        if flag_.Usage == "" {
            return
        }
        s := fmt.Sprintf("  -%s", flag_.Name) // Two spaces before -; see next two comments.
        name, usage := flag.UnquoteUsage(flag_)
        if len(name) > 0 {
            s += " " + name
        }
        // Boolean flags of one ASCII letter are so common we
        // treat them specially, putting their usage on the same line.
        if len(s) <= 4 { // space, space, '-', 'x'.
            s += "\t"
        } else {
            // Four spaces before the tab triggers good alignment
            // for both 4- and 8-space tab stops.
            s += "\n    \t"
        }
        s += strings.ReplaceAll(usage, "\n", "\n    \t")
        _, _ = fmt.Fprint(f.Output(), s, "\n")
    })
}
flag.Parse()
```